# jQuery clone() doesn't copy <select> DOM properties?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider the following HTML :

```
<a id="add" herf="#">add</a>

<div class="list">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And Javascript :

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var copy = $('.list').last().clone();
    copy.appendTo('body');
});
```

(OR : http://jsfiddle.net/5A5pN/)

If you choose a select option before clicking  `Add`, you'll notice the newly added select box still uses 1 as its original value, not 2.

Any ways to overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742810/clone-isnt-cloning-select-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES! but you can do a workaround. like this,

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var orig = $('select',$('.list').last());
    var copy = $('.list').last().clone();
    $('select',copy).val(orig.val());
    copy.appendTo('body');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5A5pN/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worked like a charm. Would really appreciate if you could briefly explain how it works.