# copy/Clone dropdown list with selected option in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

How can I clone dropdown list(combobox) with selected option?

jquery .clone method is not working in **firefox** for selected option.

I have a div having different controls. I have to copy entire div to a variable something like this

```
var $orginalDiv = $('#myDiv');
var $clonedDiv = $orginalDiv.clone();

$clonedDiv.find('select').each(function() {


....Something do here for assigning selected options from original div ..

            });
```

Let me know how can we get it done and it must be worked in FireFox.

Comment: you are maybe looking for this one, [jquery clone doesnt copy select dom properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776270/jquery-clone-doesnt-copy-select-dom-properties)

Comment: @Reigel this is for single control, but i need for multiple dropdownlist. how can i assign val in the question code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var $orginalDiv = $('#myDiv');
var $clonedDiv = $orginalDiv.clone();

//get original selects into a jq object
var $originalSelects = $orginalDiv.find('select');

$clonedDiv.find('select').each(function(index, item) {

     //set new select to value of old select
     $(item).val( $originalSelects.eq(index).val() );

});
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbWEp/2/) at jsfiddle

Comment: +1 I wasn't sure if index would work if `select`'s are not siblings, but it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/kvzam/)!

Comment: +1 Now it works.Nice Ans, shows Good experience with jQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement a button to clone the drop downs?

Comment: Yep, just use `$(dropdown).clone()` in the click handler of the button.

Comment: how to change the name and id property of the cloned dropdown.i used $(dropdown).clone().attr("name","Skill"); but its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a customedropdown with some image mask then simple clone will not display a selected value, for that you have to first assign a selected value of one dropdown to second drop down, and then call a change event implicitly like following.
$('select[id*=cstate]').val($("select[id*=state]").val());
$("#cstate").change();