# MVC3 DropDownListFor not setting selected property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

In MVC3, when using DropDownListFor is it necessary for the first parameter to be a string? I have the following setup:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyListItemId, Model.MyListItems, 
    new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { "style", "width:120px" }, 
        { "data-type", "myList" } 
    })
```

where m.MyId is an int on my viewmodel. I'm having an issue where when I change the selected item in my drop down list, and inspect the rendered html, the "selected" property is not set to the newly selected item. This is a problem as i'm using jquery clone function to copy that row and i need the list with the new selected item to be copied to my new row. Ideas?

**Update** - Changing the property on the viewmodel to a string makes no difference.
Is this a bug with mvc dropdownlistfor? I've read quite a few posts on similar issues, but can't seem to find a solution that works in this instance. This is how my list is setup in my code:

```
var myListItems = _myRepository.GetAll();
model.MyListItems = new SelectList(myListItems, "Id", "Name", lineItem.myListItemId);
model.MyListItemId = lineItem.myListItemId;
```

where lineItem is passed into this method

Comment: Not sure if I've misunderstood your question; but if you're cloning the select list with jQuery clone you need to re-select the option, see questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776270/jquery-clone-doesnt-copy-select-dom-properties?answertab=oldest) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861729/copy-clone-dropdown-list-with-selected-option-in-jquery).

Comment: thanks! i wasnt aware of that! that might help with the cloning, i'll try it now. I'm still curious though as to why the drop down list select value doesnt change in the rendered html when a new item is selected?

Comment: that's not really what i'm looking for. i can copy the selected value from the previous row, but the main problem is that the latest selected value isn't marked as selected

Answer (score 0):

No, the selected value property does not need to be a string, it can be an int. As long as the value is convertible to a string, it should work (so selected value type could be a Guid, int, bool, etc).

I have sometimes found issues when my route for the page has a route parameter with the same name as the selected value model property. For example, consider this:

```
route: "/establishments/{establishmentId}/edit"
```

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem[] Establishments { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EstablishmentId, Model.Establishments)
```

With this code, the selected value of the drop down list would always be whatever establishmentId is in the route. So if the route were /establishments/12/edit, then value 12 would be selected in the dropdown. It doesn't matter that the route parameter and model property capitalization doesn't match.

I figured this out by downloading the MVC source code, making my own copy of the DropDownListFor (named MyDropDownListFor), then stepping through the code to see what happened. If you are still having trouble with MVC3, I suggest you do the same. You need to figure out whether this is an issue with the server code, or your jquery clone stuff.

Comment: thats a good idea, i downloaded the mvc code, i added in the selectlist extensions class, its dependent on things like MvcResources, I get a compile error cannot access internal class...how do i get this to a state so i can debug it?

Comment: it has a couple refs you can just replace with anything to make it compile. For example with the exceptions, I just replaced the resources calls with my own strings. You do have to copy over some internal classes and methods. But trust me its worth it to really understand how these html helpers work in the context of your app's code.

Comment: Thanks! I debugged, but didnt find anything useful. When I select a new item, the selected item in the rendered html still remains as the previous item...