# jQuery dynamiclly added from field wont submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a bit of jQuery that allows people to add form fields dynamically based on the number of children they have.

```
var childCount = $('.newchildsub').length + 1;

$('.newchildsub:last').after($('.newchildsub:first').clone().removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'child-' + childCount).insertAfter('.newchildsub:last'));

$('#child-' + childCount).find('#childId').remove();
$('#child-' + childCount).find('#gender').attr('name', 'children[child-' + childCount + '][gender]').attr('value', '');
$('#child-' + childCount).find('#month').attr('name', 'children[child-' + childCount + '][month]').attr('value', '');
$('#child-' + childCount).find('#year').attr('name', 'children[child-' + childCount + '][year]').attr('value', '');
```

The code works prefect to add the fields and increase the name but when I click submit and `print_r($_POST);`, the dynamically created field is not there.

Below is an example of my html including the dynamically generated field (child-3), which is based of the first one as you can see in the jQuery.

```
<div id="child-1" class="newchildsub">
    <h4>Gender: </h4><input type="hidden" id="childId" name="children[child-1][id]" value="394820">
    <select name="children[child-1][gender]" id="gender">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Birthday: </h4>
    <select name="children[child-1][month]" id="month">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02" selected>February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="children[child-1][year]" id="year">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="2012" selected>2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select><br><br>
</div>

<div id="child-2" class="newchildsub">
    <h4>Gender: </h4>
    <input type="hidden" id="childId" name="children[child-2][id]" value="394821">
    <select name="children[child-2][gender]" id="gender">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female" selected>Female</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Birthday: </h4>
    <select name="children[child-2][month]" id="month">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="01" selected>January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="children[child-2][year]" id="year">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011" selected>2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select><br><br>
</div>

<div id="child-3" class="newchildsub">
    <h4>Gender: </h4>
    <select id="gender" name="children[child-3][gender]">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option selected="" value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Birthday: </h4>
    <select id="month" name="children[child-3][month]">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option selected="" value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">March</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select id="year" name="children[child-3][year]">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option selected="" value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you are changing the `id`, but not the `name` **attribute** for the cloned fields.

The `name` attribute has to be unique and that's why you don't see the dynamically added fields.

Comment: I actually do edit the name, just didn't include that jQuery by mistake. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Add your name attribute into your jQuery code.

Comment: I actually do edit the name, just didn't include that jQuery by mistake. I have edited my original post.

Comment: Try using appendTo instead of insertAfter.  From some quick research it seems the appendTo is needed to get all of the elements of the select to copy as well.  Here's another SO post talking about copying select elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776270/jquery-clone-doesnt-copy-select-dom-properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage name of your input element.
You can give them the name uniquely or give the name as un-indexed array like `children[gender][]`. Php will parse them and treat as array by creating index automatically for that. [This link may help](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Comment: I actually do edit the name, just didn't include that jQuery by mistake. I have edited my original post.

Comment: @ATLChris You cannot get element by .find('#childId').. Because id #childId is reserved by previous element. That id have to be unique also.

Comment: @ATLChris I suggest you to use un-indexed array name of elements to simplify manage them. If you insist to do not, put the class on the elements so you can find it using `.find('.className')`