# Append 1 Form to Another Form - Then Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 forms, 1 in my content and one in the sidebar of my website. I submit them via `$_GET`, but I want to submit the form when any of the selects are changed. Since they're in 2 different locations and wrapped in 2 separate form tags I need to append `#form1` to `#form2` then submit `#form2`. I've looked through the SO questions and everything deals with `:input` and `clone()` but according to the documentation `clone()` does not work with `select` boxes. It reads: [.clone() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> **Note:** For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made
>   to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input
>   elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into
>   text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the
>   cloned elements.

So how do I append a form of `select` to a separate form?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
jQuery('#form1 select, #form2 select').change(function(){

    // Tried this
    jQuery('#form1 select[name="select_name"]').append('#form2');

    // Tried this before the research
    jQuery('#form1 select').clone().hide().append('#form2');

    // Form submission works without the above code
    jQuery('#form2').submit();
});
```

Neither of the above worked, nor do I get any errors in my console. Worst comes to worst I can loop through and append the values as hidden inputs but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Why not just submit both forms at the same time?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. I'm using these forms as filtering so I need them to submit in one big query string of `$_GET` values

Comment: I know this might be a bit messy ... but is it possible to wrap both areas in the same `form` element as they are essentially the same form?

Comment: So, I am not sure what you are trying to append to what. But, in your first attempt `jQuery('#form1 select[name="select_name"]').append('#form2');` will attempt to append  `form2` to `#form1 select[name="select_name"]` and thinking about it... how can you append a form to a select element? If your intention is to append the select options from form1 to form2 then you just have to switch around those statements.

Comment: @Adjit You're right, I was using my append wrong. I ended up using `jQuery('#form2').append(jQuery('#form1 select'));` to make it work. Since you pretty much solved it, if you want to format an answer I'd gladly accept it !

Comment: Also this seems to work relatively well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776270/jquery-clone-doesnt-copy-select-dom-properties

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Glad to help. I would also observe caution when using workarounds. I think there are some really cool workarounds out there for various things, but I try to avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt

`jQuery('#form1 select[name="select_name"]').append('#form2');`

will attempt to append  `#form2` to `#form1 select[name="select_name"]`

Thinking about it... how can you append a form to a select element?

If your intention is to append the select options from form1 to form2 then you just have to switch around those statements.

`jQuery('#form2').append('#form1 select[name="select_name"]');` This will append the `select` options from `form1` to `form2`

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the forms, append the result and issue a POST:

```
$.post( url, $("#form1").serialize() + "&" + $("#form2").serialize() );
```