# Clone a row containing selects, and clone selects' values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, clone, field

I have this HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="MatchId[]" value="">
        <select name="TeamId[]">
            <optgroup label="Women">
                <option value="18">Women 1</option>
                <option value="17">Women 2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Men">
                <option value="9">Men 1</option>
                <option value="8">Men 2</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="Day[]">
            <!-- blah -->
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="addButton" type="button" value="+">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="removeButton" type="button" value="-">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to clone the row when I click on the + button, but also set the value of the `<select>` to be the same as the original row.

For now, I have this code, which successfully clones the row, but leaves the new `<select>` fields with the first value as a selection:

```
$('.addButton').livequery('click', function()
{
    var $btn = $(this);

    var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone();

    $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );
});
```

How could I do that?

Edit: subsidiary question: how could I set the focus on the first  field of the cloned row after I click on the + button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it manually:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tp7hg/

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function()
{
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $row = $btn.closest('tr')

    var $clonedRow = $row.clone();
    $clonedRow.find("select").each(function(i){
        this.selectedIndex = $row.find("select")[i].selectedIndex;
    })

    $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );
});
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I had found the answer in the same time here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742810/clone-isnt-cloning-select-values

Comment: @Joseph, Mike, and well... everyone - The only other option that I can think of would be to use val itself. I'll post an answer using that method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with using the select elements `selectedIndex`

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function()
{
    var $btn = $(this);

    var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone();

    var index = $('select', $btn.closest('tr')).prop('selectedIndex');

    $('select', $clonedRow).prop('selectedIndex', index);

    $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function into `val` which gives the index. Also, I'd recommend storing the jQuery objects in a variable so you don't have to build it for each select.

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function() {
    var $btn = $(this),
        $row = $btn.closest('tr'),
        $clonedRow = $row.clone();
        $selects = $row.find('select');

    $btn.closest('tbody').append($clonedRow);
    $clonedRow.find('select').val(function(index) {
        return $selects.eq(index).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: nice! I'll have to remember you can pass a function to val.  Is it that way for most jQuery methods? (only other one I've seen it on is filter).

Comment: @Joseph - yes, most of this kind of jQuery object has a function that you can pass in. It is very handy and hardly used.