# jquery replicating html select options but different names

Tags: jquery

I have an html dropdown :

```
<select name="name1">
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Doe</option>
<option value="3">Foo</option>
<option value="4">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Is there a jQuery function that generates the same options but a different dropdown name like:

```
<select name="name2">
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Doe</option>
<option value="3">Foo</option>
<option value="4">Bar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cloning and changing the name,

```
var $newSelect = $('select[name=name1]').clone().attr('name', 'name2');
```

`append/prepend` the $newSelect to anywhere in your document :)

Also as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628824/jquery-replicating-html-select-options-but-different-names/12628844#comment17028958_12628844) suggested you can dynamically generate the name using below approach,

```
var $newSelect = $('select[name=name1]')
                    .clone()
                    .attr('name', function(i,n) { 
                         var int = 
                                parseInt(n.match(/\d*/),10); 
                         return n.replace(/\d*/, int + 1); 
                     });
```

Comment: Don't forget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742810/clone-isnt-cloning-select-values

Comment: Perhaps it's only true in this example, but, given that example, I'd suggest: `.attr('name', function(i,n) { var int = parseInt(n.match(/\d*/),10); return n.replace(/\d*/, int + 1); });` (that's untested, but *should* increment the number 'dynamically' rather than hard-coding it within the replacement string).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `$place` is where you want to append the new combobox.

```
$select = $('select').clone();

$place.append($select.attr('name', 'name2'));
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aSheJ/)

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<jquery selector criteria>').clone().attr("name", "new_name")
```