# Dynamically creation select box options issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am using the following function to create a add options to my select box

```
  //add options to the requested select box
  addOptionsToSelect : function(__enum , obj, selected_value) {
    $(__enum).each(function(i){
       var optn = new Option(this.text, this.val)
       if(selected_value === this.val){  optn.setAttribute('selected', 'selected') } 
       $(obj)[0].options.add(optn); 
    });
    return obj
  }
```

1. `__enum` is the key value pair containing the value and the text that we pass to the select option
2. `obj` is the select box obj which is also created dynamically
3. `selected_value` is the value that needs to set as selected on the select box.

The problem here is `optn.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')` works fine in all the browsers expect IE8.

I am looking for a workaround that will allow me to set the selected value in all the browsers dynamically.

Comment: `$(obj)[0] === obj` No need to make a jQuery object if you're not going to use it.

Comment: ...in any case, try `optn.selected = true;` instead.

Comment: There's no such thing as `this.val`, it's `this.value` ?

Comment: @adeneo: *"1. `__enum` is the key value pair containing the value and the text that we pass to the select option."*

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Then it should be `$.each(__enum, function(k,v) {...` as `$(element).each` is for jQuery objects like DOM nodes.

Comment: @Raghu ...or if my above suggestion doesn't work, try adding the option to the `obj` first, then `obj.selectedIndex = obj.options.length - 1;`

Comment: Also, `$(obj)[0].options.add(optn);` makes little sense, add() is a jQuery method, so what exactly is `$(obj)[0].options` ?

Comment: To answer the question, try `$(optn).prop('selected', true)`

Comment: @adeneo: *"2. `obj` is the select box obj which is also created dynamically."* Select elements have an `.add()` method.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - if that's the case `$(obj).val(this.val)` should work as well.

Comment: @adeneo: True, as long as the option gets added first.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - and it doesn't matter what `obj` is, `$(obj)[0].options` has to be a jQuery collection of elements for add() to work.

Comment: @adeneo:  `select` elements as well as the `.options` collection have a native `.add()` method for adding `option` elements.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - that's true, but that method requires two parameters, so this is most likely the jQuery version.

Comment: @adeneo: It only requires one. The second is optional

Comment: @CrazyTrain  I tried all your possibilities, none of them are liked by IE8. I tried $(obj).val(this.val) , optn.selected = true; , optn.selected = true; and obj.selectedIndex = obj.options.length - 1;  .

Comment: I am using jquery 1.6.1 FYI

Comment: @Raghu: Did you add the new `option` element to the `select` before setting the selection?

Comment: ...in other words, put `obj.options.add(optn);` above the `if` statement instead of below.

Comment: That's odd. Try this: `var optn = new Option(this.text, this.val, false, selected_value === this.val);` Not sure if IE supports all those args.

Comment: @CrazyTrain  i think you are right , let me move that statement before i set the selected value

Comment: @CrazyTrain I tried moving that statement before i set the selection but for some reason IE is still acting like a dork

Comment: Do your option elements have `value` attributes? If so, then try `obj.value = this.val;` inside the `if` statement. If that doesn't work, then there's something else going on in your code.

Comment: @CrazyTrain You were right the method that i posted in above just works fine in all the browsers . the problem was with some other code where i was cloning this select method to get the OuterHTML of the select and the clone() used to screw up my selected values. i removed that clone() (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742810/clone-isnt-cloning-select-values) and things started working as expected across all the browsers. I would like to thank you for all your help here :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd add an option to a  like so:

```
var select = document.getElementById("drop-down");
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.innerHTML = 'hello';
select.appendChild(newOption);
```

Here's an example: [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x58V3/)