# On click, clone element to variable and append it to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and I would like to set it up so that when a user enters/selects values into the inputs and clicks the "Add" button, it will clone each of the inputs/select boxes, assign them to a variable and then append them to another element below. What i have currently is just returning `[object Object]` instead of cloning the elements. Where am I going wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $name = $('#name').clone(),
        $email = $('#email').clone(),
        $package = $('#package').clone(),
        $newRow = '<div class="name">' + $name + '</div><div class="email">' + $email + '</div><div class="package">' + $package + '</div>';
        
    $('.row').append($newRow);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
  .row > div {
    display:table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="email" />
<select id="package">
  <option value="one">Package One</option>
  <option value="two">Package Two</option>
  <option value="three">Package Three</option>
</select>

<button>ADD ROW</button>

<div class="row">

</div>
```

Comment: Do.you want to clone the form elements or do you want get the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append each cloned element to its own div. Then append all divs into the row.

[Due to a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/743871/2119863), you must force value on the cloned select box

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $name = $('<div class="name"></div>').append($('#name').clone()),
        $email = $('<div class="email"></div>').append($('#email').clone()),
        $package = $('<div class="package"></div>').append($('#package').clone());
        $package.find('#package').val($('#package').val());
    $('.row').append($name, $email, $package);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
  .row > div {
    display:table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="email" />
<select id="package">
  <option value="one">Package One</option>
  <option value="two">Package Two</option>
  <option value="three">Package Three</option>
</select>

<button>ADD ROW</button>

<div class="row">

</div>
```

---

One last thing. You shouldn't be recognizing elements by `id=` as those are meant to be unique per whole page. Try rewriting your code so you could use classes for selectors. For example:

```
<input class="i_name" />
...
$('.i_name').clone()
```

Comment: This is not a goos solution because in the end you have the the IDs multiple times in your DOM which is not allowed and will tend to errors.

Comment: That's fine, I will just switch to classes instead of IDs, this solution worked for me.

Comment: You are correct @floriangosse , shouldn't use ID as selectors. But, when you ".clone(ID)" you are cloning the first dome element. Therefore, still works.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append the cloned objects.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $name = $('#name').clone(),
        $email = $('#email').clone(),
        $package = $('#package').clone();
     
        
    $('.row').append($name);  
    $('.row').append($email);  
    $('.row').append($package);


  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
  .row > div {
    display:table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="email" />
<select id="package">
  <option value="one">Package One</option>
  <option value="two">Package Two</option>
  <option value="three">Package Three</option>
</select>

<button>ADD ROW</button>

<div class="row">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to clone each element, not extract the values, as I will be adding the ability to edit the rows later.

Comment: No worries, thank you! That is close to what I am looking for, but how would I go about building out the HTML layout so that the inputs and select boxes are within parent `div`s instead of existing on the same level in the DOM?

Comment: Simply append the elements into a div before appending to the row. by using  $name = $('<div class="name"></div>').append($name)

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what do you need but clone return an object that's why appending to a string will return into a [object Object]. Perhaps you could use outerHTML.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var $name = $('#name').clone();
        $email = $('#email').clone();
        $package = $('#package').clone();
        $newRow = '<div class="name">' + $name[0].outerHTML + '</div><div class="email">' + $email[0].outerHTML + '</div><div class="package">' + $package[0].outerHTML + '</div>';
        
    $('.row').append($newRow);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  display:table-row;
}
  .row > div {
    display:table-cell;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" />
<input id="email" />
<select id="package">
  <option value="one">Package One</option>
  <option value="two">Package Two</option>
  <option value="three">Package Three</option>
</select>

<button>ADD ROW</button>

<div class="row">

</div>
```